# Need help making my stored procedure more efficient

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like some help making my SQL Server 2016 stored procedure more efficient.  I got it to work and that is 50% of my battle but I know that many (if not most) of you folks have much more experience with SQL Server stored procedures than I do.

My code so far:

```
DECLARE @U1A nvarchar(50), @U2A nvarchar(50),
        @U3A nvarchar(50), @U4A nvarchar(50),
        @U5A nvarchar(50), @U6A nvarchar(50),
        @U7A nvarchar(50), @U8A nvarchar(50),
        @U9A nvarchar(50)

DECLARE @Jsonstring  nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @recCount int

SELECT 
    @recCount = COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    [dbo].[Staging_PersonalInformation] 
WHERE 
    jsondata IS NULL

WHILE @recCount > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 
        @U1A = [FirstName], @U2A = [MiddleName], 
        @U3A = [LastName], @U4A = [EmailAddress],
        @U5A = eraCommons, @U6A = [PositionTitle],
        @U7A = [MyNCBILink], @U8A = [UniqueID],
        @U9A = [ReferenceID]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Staging_PersonalInformation]
    WHERE 
        jsondata IS NULL

    SET @Jsonstring = '[{"name":"FirstName","value":"'+isnull(@U1A, '')+'"},{"name":"Middlename","value":"'+ISNULL(@U2A, '')+'"},{"name":"LastName","value":"'+isnull(@U3A, '')+'"},{"name":"emailaddress","value":"'+isnull(@U4A, '')+'"},{"name":"eRACommons","value":"'+ISNULL(@U5A, '')+'"},{"name":"positionTitle","value":"'+ISNULL(@U6A, '')+'"},{"name":"MyNCBILink","value":"'+ISNULL(@U7A, '')+'"},{"name":"  uniqueid","value":"'+ISNULL(@U8A, '')+'"},{"name":"ReferenceID","value":"'+ISNULL(@U9A, '')+'"}]'

    UPDATE Staging_PersonalInformation
    SET JsonData = @Jsonstring
    WHERE (EmailAddress = @U4A);

    SET @recCount = @recCount - 1
END
```

The purpose of this is to take the individual column values and make a string that my sterilized JavaScript form can repopulate. I would rather store the string than to make it on the fly each time.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just curious, but why is your json name/value instead of named attributes?

Comment: When you sterilize a form with jQuery thats the format that is produced.  Then the application pulls that back and repopulates the form by loop and filling in input fields.  The next step is to convert the application to reformat in standard json and repopulate in standard json.  But this will help to import data from an excel spreadsheet and fill the database the way the application is sending the data and the application does not need to be changed "yet". so no down time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the biggest issue is that looping is horribly inefficient. And since you are always going to update this column based on values already in the table you could use a computed column and avoid all this work entirely.

I would suggest that in the future you give your variable names something meaningful instead of just numbering them.

Here is how you could make this a computed column. You can read more about computed columns here. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx

```
alter table [dbo].[Staging_PersonalInformation]
add jsondata as '[{"name":"FirstName","value":"' + isnull(FirstName, '')
    + '"},{"name":"Middlename","value":"' + ISNULL(MiddleName, '')
    + '"},{"name":"LastName","value":"' + isnull(LastName, '')
    + '"},{"name":"emailaddress","value":"'+isnull(EmailAddress, '')
    + '"},{"name":"eRACommons","value":"'+ISNULL(eraCommons, '')
    + '"},{"name":"positionTitle","value":"'+ISNULL(PositionTitle, '')
    + '"},{"name":"MyNCBILink","value":"'+ISNULL(MyNCBILink, '')
    + '"},{"name":"  uniqueid","value":"'+ISNULL(UniqueID, '')
    + '"},{"name":"ReferenceID","value":"'+ISNULL(ReferenceID, '')
    + '"}]'
```

Comment: first I agree about my variable should be and normally they are something meaningful, my fault for not changing them.   Now this is one of the reasons that I post a question here, some of you folks are just damn brilliant and can see something from a totally different direction than me.  I totally love this idea and will give it a try

Comment: Cool. Glad this worked for you. Make sure to read about the PERSISTED option. If you don't specify persisted this value will be calculated as it needs it and not stored in the table. If you have a large table this will greatly help by not duplicating the data in your table.

Comment: This is working great.  Since this is just a staging table it will be imported without the calculated field but just the value into production right after being created.  The end user is uploading an Excel spreadsheet that has been converted in to JSON and then in a Stored Proc using ms sql 2016 new OPENJSON parsed and put into the staging table.  Once that is successful it is put into production.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Sean Lange is a great answer, but I am curious as to why you are not taking advantage of SQL Server 2016 support of `for json`.

I realize that the format is not the same as you specified, so I suppose that could be the reason. Perhaps this format would also work?:

```
select * 
from Staging_PersonalInformation 
for json auto, include_null_values
```

dbfiddle.uk demo: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d533c6d3b82fdd7865b3817fba94037d

returns:

```
[{"Id":1,"FirstName":"Sean","MiddleName":null,"LastName":"Lange","EmailAddress":null,"PositionTitle":null,"MyNCBILink":null,"UniqueID":"6E6732A9-9FC9-4B6E-8695-AF6BB2DA2152","ReferenceID":0}
,{"Id":2,"FirstName":"Sql","MiddleName":null,"LastName":"Zim","EmailAddress":null,"PositionTitle":null,"MyNCBILink":null,"UniqueID":"FA33808B-E8BE-41B5-AA89-DA8A37503F8F","ReferenceID":0}]
```

Reference:

- [JSON support in SQL Server 2016 - Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/json-support-in-sql-server-2016/)
- [JSON Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server)
- [Include Null Values in JSON - `include_null_values` Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/include-null-values-in-json-include-null-values-option)

Comment: First I love the new JSON functions in 2016 and that was a major factor about how I went with for external hosting.  The entire process is that an Excel spreadsheet is converted into JSON and uploaded to a webservice that calls a stored proc.  The Stored Proc takes the JSON object and using OPENJSON it stores all of the data into the staging table field by field.  Once the data is entered and the computed column does it thing, the jsonData fields and some other info is passed into the production database.

Comment: The weird format is a function of jQuery and is currently needed to repopulate the fields in the form since only the jsonData is passed back to the HTML5 application.  So the entire form no matter how many fields is saved and repopulated from that weird format

Comment: I do "plan" on rewriting the application to use standard conventional JSON but only as time permits and we all know how that goes.  For now this is great.  And the more I can use the new JSON functions in 2016 the better it will be

Comment: @user1314159 Good to know!